# Angular 2 router does not reRoute to the right route after upgarding to RC.3

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with the function `navigate` in the router since a change of angular 2 version. I upgraded the version from **2.0.0-rc.1** to **2.0.0-rc.3**
so I had to change the version of the router like this :

@angular/router : **2.0.0-rc.1** to **3.0.0-alpha.7**

and I created a file with all the routes in it.

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: Home, terminal: true },
    { path: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: 'login', component: Login },
    ...
```

and then I added the routes to the bootstrap function

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    AppWebservice,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(Config, {useClass: Config})
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I have a component with this code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('isLoggedin: ' + isLoggedin())
    if (isLoggedin()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}
```

In this component the code `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` works nicely with 2.0.0-rc.1 but now it doesn't work with the new version.
I checked the value of `isLoggedin()` and when it's value is false I still be re-rerouted to the Home page and not to the Login page.

Does anyone know why the router does not work properly ?

Comment: check this link http://victorsavkin.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

Comment: @kTn Thank you :) I especially read the part about "Matching strategies and redirects" but I did not solve my problem with it. Maybe I misunderstood something or were you thinking of another part of the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example of how you should set up a Guard for your routes.

Add `canActivate: [HomeGuard]` on the route/s you need redirection.

You will need to create a service for `isLoggedin` to be injected into the guard.

And of course create the Guard Injectable.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: Home, terminal: true, canActivate: [HomeGuard]},
    { path: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: 'login', component: Login },


  @Injectable()
  export class HomeGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(provate isLoggedinService: IsLoggedinService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate() {
      console.log('this.isLoggedinService.isLoggedin: ' + this.isLoggedinService.isLoggedin())
      if (this.isLoggedinService.isLoggedin()) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
          return false;
      } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
          return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried with `this.router.navigateByUrl('login');` and with `this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');` and it doesn't work :/

Comment: Have you tried adding a Guard with canActivate on the routes?

Comment: No at the moment I was planning to do that tomorrow if I do not find a solution today.

Comment: Thx It was the solution to do